# Bootstrap 3 Navbar Components Align

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, alignment, navbar

I want to know how to align bootstrap components in the navbar, for example :

Brand          Menu 1  Menu 2  Menu 3  Menu 4

I need to know how to make it this way :

Menu 4  Menu 3  Menu 2  Menu 1         Brand

Here is the html code for a similar bootstrap website's navbar i want to inverse

```
  <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#top-nav">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="bootstrapwizard logo" /></a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="top-nav">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#slider">Slider</a></li>
                <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#icon-box">Icons</a></li>
                <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#featured">Featured</a></li>
                <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#showcase">Showcase</a></li>
                <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#grid">Grid</a></li>
                <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <!-- ./navigation -->
```

Thanks guys !

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs! - http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-component-alignment

You can align components using the `navbar-right` and `navbar-left` classes. So in your case you can do this

```
  <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#top-nav">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="bootstrapwizard logo" /></a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="top-nav">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#slider">Slider</a></li>
                <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#icon-box">Icons</a></li>
                <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#featured">Featured</a></li>
                <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#showcase">Showcase</a></li>
                <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#grid">Grid</a></li>
                <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <!-- ./navigation -->
```